# Gulp exits after running

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, livereload, gulp-watch

I am trying to get live reload working with express server using gulp

However gulp exits as below after running and am not able to hit the server

cmd output:

> D:\Users\workspace\server>gulp server
> [11:31:56] Using gulpfile D:\Users\workspace\server\gulpfile.js
>
> [11:31:56] Starting 'server'...
>
> [11:31:56] Finished 'server' after 26 ms
>
> livereload[tiny-lr] listening on 35729 ...
>
> D:\Users\workspace\server>

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var server = require('gulp-express');

gulp.task('server', function () {
   // Start the server at the beginning of the task 
server.run(['app.js']);

// Restart the server when file changes 
gulp.watch(['app/**/*.html'], server.notify);
gulp.watch(['app/styles/**/*.scss'], ['styles:scss']);
//gulp.watch(['{.tmp,app}/styles/**/*.css'], ['styles:css', server.notify]); 
//Event object won't pass down to gulp.watch's callback if there's more than one of them. 
//So the correct way to use server.notify is as following: 
gulp.watch(['{.tmp,app}/styles/**/*.css'], function(event){
    gulp.run('styles:css');
    server.notify(event);
    //pipe support is added for server.notify since v0.1.5, 
    //see https://github.com/gimm/gulp-express#servernotifyevent 
});

gulp.watch(['app/scripts/**/*.js'], ['jshint']);
gulp.watch(['app/images/**/*'], server.notify);
gulp.watch(['app.js', 'routes/**/*.js'], [server.run]);
});

gulp.task('default', ['server']);
```

[gulpjs tutplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/gulp-as-a-development-web-server--cms-20903)

Is there something fundamentally incorrect in the way I am calling gulp?

Comment: `gulp-express` is deprecated and hasn't been maintained for a year now. Use [`gulp-live-server`](https://github.com/gimm/gulp-live-server) instead.

Comment: What do you mean by live reload?

Answer (score 0):

Even I had some issues getting the live reload working. Hence I started using gulp-nodemon to create the webserver and live reload. Below is the task that I have:

```
    gulp.task('server', function(){  
        var nodeOptions = {
            script:"",//path to the app.js or server.js 
            delayTime: 1,
            env: {
                'PORT': 8088 //port that you want to run it on
            },
            watch: ['filesToBeWatched.js'] //files to be watched for changes
        };

        return nodemon(nodeOptions)
            .on('restart', function(event){
                console.log('Node Server RESTARTED');
            })
            .on('start', function(){
                console.log('Node Server STARTED');
                startBrowserSync();
            })
            .on('crash', function() {
                console.log('Node Server CRASHED');
            })
            .on('exit', function() {
                console.log('Node Server EXISTED')
            });

    });
```